# Updating exchange rates - VBA - Run-time error 13 Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a function, which is updating exchange rates depending on date and currency symbol - and it works well. But when I want to change some values (from PLN to, for example, USD) in my worksheet (in defined range), the loop is interputed (in bolded line). Moreover, the range where the exchange rates were saved, change to #ARG!. Below the code of function and loop:

```
Function PobierzKurs(kurs As String, data As Date)
    Dim hReq As Object
    Dim objxml As Object
    Dim link As String
    Dim odpowiedz As String

    link = "http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/" & kurs & "/" & Format(data, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "/?format=xml"

    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", link, False
        .Send
    End With

    odpowiedz = hReq.ResponseText

    If odpowiedz Like "*Brak danych" Then
        PobierzKurs = "Brak danych"
    Else
        Set objxml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        objxml.LoadXML (odpowiedz)
        PobierzKurs = objxml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Item(3).ChildNodes.Item(0).ChildNodes.Item(2).nodeTypedValue
        PobierzKurs = CDbl(Replace(PobierzKurs, ".", ","))
    End If
End Function
```

```
Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rFound As Range

    Set rFound = Nothing
    For Each r In Sheets("Raport").Range("K1:S5000")
        If InStr(1, r.Text, "zł") > 0 Then
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                Set rFound = r
            Else
                Set rFound = Union(rFound, r)
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then rFound.Select
    For Each r In rFound
   ** r.Value = r.Value / Range("$L$14").Value**
    r.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 [$USD]"
    Next r
```

What is really interesting, it was working good few days before.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkADG.jpg)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr2kG.jpg)

Comment: Beg your pardon, but what is the connection between upper code and lower code?

Comment: Try removing `rFound.Select` after `If Not rFound Is Nothing Then` and adding `End if` after the `For Each r In rFound` loop

Comment: Upper code - it`s function, which updates exchange rates
Bottom code - it`s a part of CASE structure - when I try do execute macro it fails in bolded line

Comment: Try going to the range in your worksheet where this function ```PobierzKurs``` is located and maybe reapply it (```F2``` + ```Enter```, or just select it and ```Enter```). It seems fine to me, but might be that you're having some connection issues. I suppose the bottom code is throwing an error because ```Range("$L$14").Value``` is not a number.

Comment: Also try specifying sheet name before parsing `Range("$L$14").Value`, e.g. `Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("$L$14").Value`. Alternatively, add `Debug.Print r.Value, Range("$L$14").Value` before the error line to see what are the actual values in the Immediate Window.

Comment: It tried it - I upload a screenshot to main post - macro works sometimes for some values and after it, it stops

Comment: What`s more - when I set breakpoints (screenshot2), and click play, play, and so on... - it works, exchange rates remains (not change to #ARG!)

Comment: Thanks Martin for checking. I just posted some potential solutions, hope one of them will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your function for retrieving FX rates (`Function PobierzKurs`) recalculates each time your second macro converts values from Polish Zloty to USD.

As the looping process is fast, your Function sometimes doesn't have enough time to recalculate a given exchange rate, thus an error. It also explains why going through the code with a breakpoint produces the result (when manually stepping through the code, `Function PobierzKurs` has enough time to recalculate the FX values).

There are two potential solutions that you can try on your side -

**1)** You can either add `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the very beginning of your code (the one with `r.Value`) and finish it off with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

**2)** You can store the value of cell L14 in a variable (e.g. `dim lngFX as Long` // `lngFx = Sheets("Raport").Range("L14").Value` and then use it in your calculation: `r.Value = r.Value / lngFX`

Comment: The first solution works very well! Thank You so much!